# How to dispose of old buttons

Tags: java

CI'm trying to write Conway's Game of Life program using `cell[][]` for a grid where `cell` is a `JButton`, `boolean` condition and coordinates. I've got a method which creates a new N x M grid of `cell` objects. I can easily make it bigger, but making it smaller is a problem: old buttons stay where they were. Just nulling `cell[][]` doesn't work. What should I use to dispose of old buttons?

Upd8: some code

Grid creation:

```
if(tfSizeX.getText().length() > 0 && tfSizeY.getText().length() > 0 && tfCellSize.getText().length() > 0)
{
    grid = null; // Cell[][] grid;
    int sizeGridX = Integer.parseInt(tfSizeX.getText());
    int sizeGridY = Integer.parseInt(tfSizeY.getText());
    int sizeCell = Integer.parseInt(tfCellSize.getText());
    grid = new Cell[sizeGridX][sizeGridY];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeGridX; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < sizeGridY; j++)
            grid[i][j] = new cell(i*(sizeCell+1), j*(sizeCell+1), panel, sizeCell);
    panel.repaint();
}
```

cell.java

```
public class Cell 
{
private JButton cell;
private boolean condition;
int locX, locY, size = 24;

public Cell(int locX, int locY, JPanel panel, int size)
{
    this.size = size;

    condition = false;
    cell = new JButton("");
    cell.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            if(!condition)
            {
                cell.setBackground(Color.black);
            }
            else
            {
                cell.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            condition = !condition;
        }
    });
    cell.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    cell.setBounds(locX, locY, size, size); 
    panel.add(cell);
    cell.setBackground(Color.white);
}

public void change(boolean condition)
{
    this.condition = condition;
    if(condition)
    {
        cell.setBackground(Color.black);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could we perhaps see some code?

Comment: Classes should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: 2JackWhiteIII
Got that. What about button disposal?

Comment: I'm kinda lazy to read all that code, but have you tried with button.setVisible(false)?

Comment: I don't need to just set them invisible, I need to dispose of them completely so they wouldn't take memory.